# Why Duplicate value is not getting removed

Tags: python, list

all the duplicate values are getting removed except 22. why so and what will be the solution?[image]

Comment: Don't post code as images. Have you tried debugging this by printing `l1` too?

Comment: And also don't remove elements while you iterate over it. Instead make a copy.

Comment: @AKX yes its not working